# Embed PowerApp in SharePoint Online page and get URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, embedded

I'm considering creating a single Power App application and embed it in a SharePoint Site. The SharePoint site will be provisioned through a workflow and the Power App will be added to the site through the workflow also.

I want the Power App to pickup the SharePoint Site URL its embedded on and then filter data accordingly but I cannot find a way to get Power App to read the URL. Reading an old blog (2019) it states its not possible - https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Get-SharePoint-Online-Site-Page-URL-in-PowerApp/td-p/412612

Is this still the case and are there any workarounds?

Comment: I was wondering if you can help me.
I took your previous advice and am passing a parameter to my Power app.
However I'm running into a problem.
The Parameter passes successfully.. but I can't get the referring page URL or title to be passed as a parameter. Here's exactly that I'm trying to do.
In the footer of my SharePoint site, I want to put a power apps that will tell me of any errors a person finds on the page. So, the parameter i want to pass is the current page's URL OR Title. I can't find a way to do that as a link in the footer. Here's what I currently have (I changed the URL of the po

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fetch the SharePoint page URL in canvas app directly.

However, while embedding Power app web link on SharePoint page, you can pass the query string parameter (`&parametername=parametervalue`) with site URL, which can be retrieved in canvas app using **Param()** function.

Read more about Param function at: [Launch and Param functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-param)

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use the Power Apps web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-power-apps-web-part-6285f05e-e441-408a-99d7-aa688195cd1c)

---

**Update from comments**:

You will pass the site URL as param in **Power apps web part configuration**:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thats an interesting concept, however what would happen if a user visits the site using the site name alone (in most cases the parameter would be missing), this PowerApp will lose its reference?

Comment: That should not be the problem as long as you pass correct site URL (as you need) as param to app web link in **Power apps web part configuration** (property pane) >> see updated answer.